# recently used programs stopped updating Vista Home Premium 64

Tags: windows, windows-vista, start-menu

For some reason my list of recently used programs has stopped updating.

Any program that I "pin" to the start menu remains, but where  you would normally expect to see the recent programs is just blank space.

What setting do you think could have changed? I don't recall changing anything.

Thanks!

**edit**
Start Menu>Properties > Privacy "Store and display a list of recently used programs" is indeed checked.

Comment: I'm coincidentally having the same problem. However, I've just removed a major malware infection and I know at least some of the users' profiles are corrupt as a result, so I'm doing an in-place upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, uninstalling "CCLeaner" and reinstalling appeared to have fixed this. Whether or not this is related I do not know.

Reinstalled it to update it to latest version.